# How to log CPU instructions executed by a Python program?

Tags: python, assembly, reverse-engineering

I understand that Python source code is compiled into bytecode which is then interpreted by the Python VM (let's say CPython). If I understand correctly, this mean that the VM parses the bytecode instructions and decides (at runtime) what CPU instructions should be executed accordingly.

**My questions:**

- Is it possible to log the actual CPU instructions executed on your machine as a result of the interpretation of a particular Python file (.py)? I understand it might not be simple (or even feasible) to get a 1-1 correspondence between a .py file and CPU instructions, but what is the closest you can get?
- **Going a step further:** Is it even possible to log the instructions executed that correspond to a particular process?

Comment: I probably don't understand what it is that you want to see but in the off chance that it's along these lines and you don't know the module: does [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) get you closer to what you're looking for? Obviously it's not logging in real time.

Comment: Disclaimer: My question is mostly curiosity-driven. I suspect looking at CPU actual instructions might be impractical for interpreted code. I just wonder if it's possible.

Comment: feel free to ask reverse engineering questions on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `strace` on linux, it will show you every system call made by any program (including python). On windows you have to use something like [wt](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2009/10/12/special-commandtracing-applications-using-wt/) or maybe [Logger.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/logger-and-logviewer) which traces all library calls (not just system).

You can use a debugger like `gdb` to look at the machine code in realtime, and since you have CPython source code, a better alternative is to just compile it with debugging symbols then run it in a C debugger, that can give you a high-level call stack, which will be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Is _just_ getting the system calls the best you can do? Is it not possible to observe the CPU instructions in more detail?

Comment: @81rect I thought you asked for system calls. Edited my answer. `gdb` is what you want

Comment: Oh wow, it's possible to use `gdb` on python directly, didn't imagine that! This answers my first question, thanks. How about observing a process in general? I mean... debuggers work by pausing execution and observing variable like registers right? If you don't have the CPU instructions hardcoded like in the case of disassembing a program (say C), is it impossible to know what CPU instructions actually ran?

Comment: `gdb` is a wonderful piece of software. It can generate a log of instructions. Heck, it can record and replay execution, with rewinding support!

Comment: This old wiki page https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb specifically deals with using gdb to debug python. Can give you some pointers in the right direction maybe?

Comment: `gdb` can record... ok this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @81rect: The CPython interpreter is written in C or C++.  Its code is x86 machine instructions.  Any time a process stops, it stops with RIP = the start of the next instruction.  That's still true if you were using a Python interpreter that JIT-compiles python to x86 machine code on the fly: RIP will point into a dynamically allocated page of memory holding x86 machine code.  (Assuming you're on x86 of course).  There is no magic, everything happens by the CPU running machine code.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's what I had in mind, I just didn't imagine tools like gdb can be used on languages like Python and even record the machine code ran.

Comment: @81rect:   An interpreter loop can be as simple as a big `switch()` statement.  (Interpreters have the interesting effect of turning decoding sequential VM code into a control dependency, but branching in the VM is just a data dependency in the interpreter code.)

Comment: @81rect: You're *not* using `gdb` *on python code*, you're using it on the x86 machine code of the python *interpreter*, which is itself a program.  Interpreting a Python `+` operator involves running boatloads of instructions, not just an `add rax, rcx`.  You'd only get that from a JIT compiler.  But yes, you can debug any user-space process, everything is just machine code at the lowest level.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I understand that the program running is the intepreter and that python bytecode is just the input of that program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I looked at the CPU instructions of CPython using [`lldb`](https://lldb.llvm.org/) (it's similar to [`gdb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger)) through [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) on my [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family) CPU (macOS 13 running on [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)):

1. Install the [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) VS Code extension
2. `git clone https://github.com/python/cpython.git`
3. `cd cpython`
4. `git checkout 20cf32e761` (because the latest code might be broken)
5. Compile CPython (see the [README file](https://github.com/python/cpython#build-instructions) or [how they build it for testing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a35fd38b57d3eb05074ca36f3d57e1993c44ddc9/.github/workflows/build.yml#L167-L173) for details), which will generate an executable file called "python.exe":

```bash
brew install pkg-config openssl@1.1 xz gdbm tcl-tk

CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix gdbm)/include -I$(brew --prefix xz)/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix gdbm)/lib -I$(brew --prefix xz)/lib" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib/pkgconfig" \
./configure \
  --with-pydebug \
  --with-openssl="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"

make
```

6. Open the CPython source code directory in VS Code (`code .`) and add a .vscode/launch.json file with these contents (set `args` to the arguments you want to pass to the `python` executable, in this example I'm running `python -c '30858 + 7'`, which just gets Python to add 30858 + 7 and exit without printing anything):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/python.exe",
            // Add two integers
            "args": ["-c", "30858 + 7"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

7. Add a breakpoint somewhere. Interesting places to put a breakpoint are [the `main()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c67ec394faac79d260804d569a18fab43018af0/Programs/python.c#L15) or the evaluation loop (a giant `switch` statement [that looks at the opcode](https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-4-how-python-bytecode-is-executed/)) which will be in generated_cases.c.h (it's not in the source code) or for my `30858 + 7` example, [`_PyLong_Add()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a35fd38b57d3eb05074ca36f3d57e1993c44ddc9/Objects/longobject.c#L3474) which is what implements addition.
8. Press F5 to run the command

At this point you should've hit the breakpoint and be able to see where the execution is in the C code. To look at the current assembly instruction, hit Cmd+Shift+P and execute the "LLDB: Show Disassembly..." command and choose "always", you can go back to the C view by running the command again and choosing "auto". You can see the register values under the "Registers" dropdown in the top left, under where the current variable values are.

Here's the machine instruction that is adding `30858` (`788A` in hex), stored in register x20 to `7`, stored in register x0, and storing the result in register x0 (I modified the code a bit to put the addition on a separate line to make it easier to set the breakpoint exactly at the `add` instruction):

[image: screenshot of VS Code]